# From VBA for MS word: finding the position on paper a Range will print

Tags: vba, ms-word

Given a `Range` object in VBA for MS Word, I need to find where it will be printed on paper.

## Context

I have about 40 related word templates for letters. They must be printed and send automatically and therefore, the address information should for all templates be at the same place on paper. The addresses are inserted in `Field` objects via mail merge.

To find out which ones I need to correct, I wrote

```
Sub screen_fields()
    Dim Fld As Field
    For Each Fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
        Debug.Print Fld.Result.Start, Fld.Result.Font.Name, Fld.Result.Font.Size, Fld.Code
    Next
End Sub
```

but the start position appears to be in characters, not in centimeters, dots or inches.

Is there a property of the `Range` object or a function on it that can tell me where it will be printed?

As the documents heavily use tables, finding the position of a cell in a table would be a partial solution.

Comment: Often measurements are in `point`... Out of curiosity, how did you establish it's measured in `Characters`?

Comment: Because the difference of `Fld.Result.Start` and `Fld.Result.End` is the length of `Fld.Result.Text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is to use the `Information` property of the `Range` object.

```
.Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
```

However, as macropod pointed out in his answer your problem can be solved by editing the template. You need to ensure that if there are any merge fields above the address they cannot expand to push the address down. That is not something that you can discover through code alone.

Answer (score 0):

Testing field lengths before a merge executes is not terribly helpful, as the merge fields ordinarily don't reflect the length of the data they'll output. Post-merge, there's no field to test.

This kind of thing is typically an issue with addresses. If you put such fields in a table of fixed height and width, large enough to accommodate the largest address, the rest of your output document's page layout will remain the same regardless of the size of the address.

No code required.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with my question? Because I don't see it.

Comment: @DirkHorsten  You have asked an XY question.  I have symptom X how do I deal with it. 
 Everyone looks at your symptom and says you have problem X this is how you solve X (and hence Y) but you don't listen because you are only interested in Y.

Comment: I clearly said I have problem Y, though. My problem is not that texts don't fit in table cells, like you apparently understood. It is about finding out coordinates on paper.

Comment: Aha! Maybe you did not onderstand __always on the same place__ like I intended it, so I replaced it by __for all templates on the same place__.

Comment: That still does not make it an XY problem, though.

Comment: Not much sign of  "Analyst and developer, curious towards data, persevering in getting things right and thinking out of the box if needed."  Its the design of the templates you need to be looking at, not where am I printing on the page.